# Adding my form data to the database using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

Hi there I am struggling with getting my form to post its data to MySQL database.

I have a config file setup like this:

```
 // server info
 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $db = 'cms';

 // connect to the database
 $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

 // show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

---

The form php page:

```
 <?php
 include("config_database.php")
  ?>


 <?php
 include("addproduct.php")
  ?>


<article>

  <section class="Input">

     <fieldset><legend><span> Add a product to the database </span></legend>


         <form action="addproduct.php" method="post">
          <label> product name: </label><input type="text" name="name"><br />
          <label> product quantity: </label><input type="text" name="quantity"><br />
          <label> product description: </label><input type="text" name="description"><br />                    
           <label> product price: </label><input type="text" name="price"><br />
           <input type="submit" class="reg">
           </form>
```

---

then a "addproduct.php" to hopefully send the data to the database:

```
   require_once ("config_database.php");

    if (isset($_POST['name']) &&
    !empty($_POST["name"]) &&


isset($_POST['quantity']) &&
    !empty($_POST["quantity"]) &&


isset($_POST['description']) &&
    !empty($_POST["description"]) &&


isset($_POST['price']) &&
    !empty($_POST["price"]))

 {
$name      = get_post('name');
$quantity    = get_post('quantity');
$description = get_post('description');
$price = get_post('price');



 $query = "INSERT INTO products VALUES" .
    "('', '$name', '$quantity', '$description', '$price')";


}
function get_post($var)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

How do I get the data entered in my form into my database?

Comment: Struggling as in? That's a pretty vague description IMO. Also your `$query` is just a string. It needs to be fed to the query method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try the insert query like this using mysqli.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products VALUES (NULL, '$name','$quantity', '$description','$price')";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

and also use real escape string like this for mysqli.

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
```